# Loading data from a text file to a table in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have got 2 questions.

1. Is there any way to load data to a table in Oracle from a `.txt` file other than using SQL loader?
2. How to unload data from the table to a text file?

Someone please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

There are a bunch of options.  It depends on the context - your Oracle version, data format, is this on the client or the server, etc.  Here's a quick list, there are probably many other methods:

**File Input:**

- [UTL_FILE](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_file.htm#ARPLS069)
- [SQL*Loader](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/part_ldr.htm#i436326)
- [DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.READ2CLOB](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_xslpro.htm#ARPLS70162)
- [External Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/tablecls.htm#CNCPT1141)
- [xmltype.createXML](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/t_xml.htm#ARPLS71959) with BFILE
- [Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html) or other third-party tool

**File Output:**

- [UTL_FILE](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_file.htm#ARPLS069)
- [Data Dump Utility](http://www.oracle-developer.net/content/utilities/data_dump.sql) (wrapper around UTL_FILE)
- [DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.CLOB2FILE](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_xslpro.htm#ARPLS70151)
- [External Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/tablecls.htm#CNCPT1141)
- [SQL*Plus script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/956645/getting-output-in-flat-file-using-oracle-on-unix)
- [Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html) or other third-party tool

Answer (score 1):

1. Load data from txt file other than sql loader - External table,UTL_FILE package
2. Unload data - UTL_FILE package

Use google with these key words you will find lot of information.

Comment: In informix there is a simple function like "load from" for this purpose. What i wanted to ask is whether something like that which is simple exists in oracle or not

Comment: The closest is an EXTERNAL TABLE

Answer (score 0):

**Curreent Solution: Load data with SQL* Loader (2016  using Windows 10 and Oracle client  12c)**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39649776/3377472

Answer (score -1):

For unloading the data you can just spool the file. In SQLPLUS create a spool file and then run a select query that reads from a table, format the data and return a string. The data will be written to the file.

Other solutions have already been mentioned. The tools including TOAD have features to create files.

Answer (score -1):

This is an old topic but I think the following info can help a lot:

```
|-----------------|----------------|----------------|
| LOAD METHOD     | DATA ON CLIENT | DATA ON SERVER |
|-----------------|----------------|----------------|
| SQL*Plus        | Yes            | No             |
| SQL*Loader      | Yes            | No             |
| External Tables | No             | Yes            |
| BFILES          | No             | Yes            |
|-----------------|----------------|----------------|
```

Source: https://blogs.oracle.com/searchtech/loading-documents-and-other-file-data-into-the-oracle-database

Answer (score -1):

Haven't used it for a few years but PL/SQL Developer has a text importer tool. I'm fairly sure that I have it documented somewhere but you need PL/SQL Developer as a starting point. If you Google "sql developer text importer" you'll get all the info you need.

Answer (score -2):

Oracle has a free tool SQL Developer (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html) you can use to do these.