# Transfer data from Oracle table to text file

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I'm interested is it possible with PL/SQL block to transfer the content of a Oracle table into text file on the Hard Drive. I need a PL/SQL block which can download the content of a table witch will be used to store log data into text file.

Regards

Comment: Have a look at the following link http://www.dbforums.com/oracle/805663-pl-sql-how-spool-my-output-files.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loading data from a text file to a table in oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750538/loading-data-from-a-text-file-to-a-table-in-oracle)

Comment: Do you want to write at client side or server side. Use UTL_FILE for server side and client side you can spool from sql*plus

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use UTL_file package for this..

you can try below type of block --

```
declare 
p_file util_file.file_type;
l_table <your_table_name>.ROWTYPE;
l_delimited varchar2(1) := '|';
begin
p_file:= utl_file.fopen('<file_path>','<file_name>','W');
for l_table in (select * from <your_table_name>) loop
utl_file.putline(p_file,l_table.col1||l_delimited||l_table.col2||l_delimited||l_table.col3||l_delimited||l_table.col4||l_delimited <continue with column list .........> ||chr(10));
end loop;    
utl_file.fclose_all();
end;
```

Comment: This will download all information from a table into file? How I can run this code for example every 10 minutes?

Comment: you haven't ask this condition in question .. but this is also possible .. you can use schedules to run this job ..

Comment: I just gave you a beginning you can extend this in which form you want ..  :)

Comment: you can refer website http://www.dba-oracle.com/tips_oracle_dbms_job.htm for scheduling ...

Answer (score 4):

pratik garg's answer is a good one.
But, you might want to consider also the use of an [EXTERNAL TABLE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/et_concepts.htm).
Basically, it's a table which is mapped to a file. So every row inserted to the table is automatically written to a file.
you can see an example [here](http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2007/04/28/writing-data-to-a-text-file-from-oracle/)