# Bulk insert in oracle

Tags: oracle, db2, bulkinsert

I need to insert the huge records that are comes as Interface file(text files).
Now am using this format to insert records.

```
INSERT ALL
  INTO POSTAL_CODE( postal_code,desc)
    VALUES('100','Coimbatore')
  INTO POSTAL_CODE (postal_code,desc)
    VALUES('101','Mumbai') SELECT * FROM DUAL;
```

But this gives bad performance. I am new to database. So please help me to make faster inserting records. But in db2 this format is supports.

```
INSERT INTO POSTAL_CODE( postal_code,desc)
    VALUES('100','Coimbatore'), (postal_code,desc),('101','Mumbai');
```

But why oracle is not support this type of insert. Please help me. Am stuck with this. I need to use another solution for this and that should be faster....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to do multi-row insert in Oracle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39576/best-way-to-do-multi-row-insert-in-oracle)

Comment: How many rows are inserted at one time?  If it's more than a few hundred you may be running into the same problem as in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11656026/409172).  The solution is to break the statement into a few hundreds rows per run, and convert `INSERT ALL` into `UNION ALL` like in Rahul's answer.

Comment: Upto 3 million records inserting at one time jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the below statement

```
INSERT INTO POSTAL_CODE( postal_code,desc) VALUES('100','Coimbatore'),
(postal_code,desc),('101','Mumbai');
```

To be like below using `UNION` which should work in `Oracle` as well

```
INSERT INTO POSTAL_CODE( postal_code,"desc") 
select '100','Coimbatore' from dual
union all
select '99','Goa' from dual
union all
select '101','Mumbai' from dual;
```

You should rather check the utilities provided by Oracle for this purpose like [`SQL*Loader`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/toc.htm)

As well check this other SO post [Loading data from a text file to a table in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750538/loading-data-from-a-text-file-to-a-table-in-oracle)